# nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar error

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

To the best of my knowedge I do not believe I am doing anything wrong however I am getting:

```
2011-04-02 14:55:23.350 AppName[42430:207] nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
2011-04-02 14:55:23.352 AppName[42430:207] nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
2011-04-02 14:55:23.729 AppName[42430:207] Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.
2011-04-02 14:55:23.729 AppName[42430:207] Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.
```

Here is my code

```
- (IBAction) btnGetCurrentLocation{
    [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Getting current location..."];
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation 
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = newLocation.coordinate;

    LocationMapViewController *locationMapViewController = [[LocationMapViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LocationMapViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    locationMapViewController.title=@"Your Title";
    locationMapViewController.centerOfMap = &(coordinate);
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:locationMapViewController animated:YES]; 

}
```

I googled it however most places talk about putting animation:NO however then I do not see the map on next screen.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525519/iphone-uinavigation-issue-nested-push-animation-can-result-in-corrupted-naviga

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are pushing a new controller every time that CLLocationManager notify a change of location from the same controller. That results in a nested navigation. Trying to hold a reference to LocationMapViewController in that controller at first time that you are being notified, and later check it to notify it:

```
if (self.locationController == null){
     LocationMapViewController *locationMapViewController = [[LocationMapViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LocationMapViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    locationMapViewController.title=@"Your Title";
    locationMapViewController.centerOfMap = &(coordinate);
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:locationMapViewController animated:YES]; 
}else{
    [self.locationController locationDidChangeTo: &(coordinate)];
}
```

Another alternative is creating the CLLocationManager in the LocationMapViewController...

Answer (score 2):

Another solution I found I could convert all my code into storyboard, and walla, it works again. sweet. its not as hard as it looks, cheers, tronnick

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you haven't pushed into navigation stack two or more `UIViewControllers` at the same time.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. It would be nice if you improved your answer by a reference and/or a bit of explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if this addresses your specific problem, but I got the `nested pop animation can result in corrupted navigation bar` message when I was trying to pop a view controller before it had appeared. Override `viewDidAppear` to set a flag in your UIViewController subclass indicating that the view has appeared (remember to call `[super viewDidAppear]` as well). Test that flag before you pop the controller. If the view hasn't appeared yet, you may want to set *another* flag indicating that you need to immediately pop the view controller, from within `viewDidAppear`, as soon as it has appeared. Like so:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
    bool didAppear, needToPop;
}
```

...and in the `@implementation`...

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    didAppear = YES;
    if (needToPop)
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)myCrucialBackgroundTask {
    // this task was presumably initiated when view was created or loaded....
    ...
    if (myTaskFailed) {  // o noes!
        if (didAppear)
            [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        else
            needToPop = YES;
    }
}
```

The duplicated `popViewControllerAnimated` call is a bit ugly, but the only way I could get this to work in my currently-tired state.