# Two UInavigationcontrollers that merge

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have kind of an odd bug.  I've got two navigation controllers in a tab bar controller.  The twist is that nav controller #2 points to view controllers in nav controller #1 as follows:

1a -> 1b -> 1c -> 1d

2a -> 1c ->1d

I have it set up in the storyboard such that there is only one instance of 1c, 1d, and 2a points to 1c with a segue.  Everything works fine (everything segues to the right thing, and unwinds too the right thing), until I start doing rotations.  When I start switching tabs, rotating and going back to the original tab, the original navigation stack has a couple of extra view controllers in it.

For example:

1. I start at 1a, click through 1b, 1c, 1d.
2. I switch tabs to 2a, click through 1c, 1d.
3. I rotate to landscape mode.
4. I unwind to 1c, then click through to 1d (still in the 2nd tab).
5. I switch tabs back to 1.
6. When I start clicking back through the navigation stack, I would expect to just unwind 1c, 1b, 1a.  However, I get a couple of extra 1c's, so my actual unwind is as follows: 1c, 1c, 1c, 1b, 1a.

Anyone know why?

Comment: If you want a tab controller with navigation ability then use one UINavigationController at the root. Then add a UITabBarController to it. Then add your views. Don't try putting multiple nav controllers into one tab controller.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who's interested, it appears that there's a bug with combining manual and storyboard segues or something that I'm failing to understand.  I had read this question: [iPhone UINavigation Issue - nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525519/iphone-uinavigation-issue-nested-push-animation-can-result-in-corrupted-naviga) but didn't think it applied because I didn't have duplicate actions, or duplicate calls to the same segue.  However, I did have 2 segues, one from a tableviewcell, and one from a button.  The button was a manual modal segue, and the tableviewcell was a push from the storyboard.  I changed the manual segue to a storyboard segue, and the bug went away.

Comment: I doubt very much that there is a bug.